# "Set" method in React Hooks is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm trying to set a state which contains the current year and the 4 years before it, but for some reason I'm not being able to set the state properly.

```
const [years, setYears] = useState({ selected: 0, availables: [] })

const getYears = () => {
  const y = {
    selected: new Date().getFullYear(),
    availables: [],
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    y.availables.push(y.selected - i)
  }

  setYears(y)
}

useEffect(() => {
  getYears()
}, [])
```

In the end, the "years" state stays with its initial values (`{selected: 0, availables: []}`).

Can anyone please help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems weird that you're using useEffect to initialize the state, do you know that you can use a function in useState to compute the initialState ?

Comment: Anyway, your code seems to work fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-colden-sd7w4

Comment: where after using setYears are you checking for its value?

Comment: thanks guys, i found out what i was doing wrong, it was related to particularities of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always simplify your logic by separating the states into `selectedYear` (number) and `availableYears` (array). But if you're intent on keeping them contained within a single object, then take a look at the example shown below. Click the **Run code snippet** button for a working example.

```js
// current year
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

// creates an array of available years where "num" represents 
// the amount to create/subtract from "year"
const createAvailableYears = (num, year) => [
  ...Array(num)
    .fill()
    .map((_, key) => year - key - 1)
];

function App() {
  const [years, setYears] = React.useState({
    selected: currentYear,
    available: createAvailableYears(4, currentYear)
  });

  const handleChange = React.useCallback(({ target: { value } }) => {
    setYears({
       // updates the selected year
       selected: value,
       // sets the available years to: [selected year - 4 years]
       available: createAvailableYears(4, value)
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <select className="select" onChange={handleChange} value={years.selected}>
        {createAvailableYears(10, 2021).map(year => (
          <option key={year} value={year}>
            {year}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <h1>Selected year: {years.selected}</h1>
      <h3>Available years: {years.available.join(", ")}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const [years, setYears] = useState({ selected: 0, availables: [] });
const getYears = () => {
  const tempSelected = new Date().getFullYear();
  let tempAvailables = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    tempAvailables.push(tempSelected - i);
  }

  setYears({ selected: tempSelected, availables: tempAvailables });
};
useEffect(() => {
  getYears();
}, []);
```

Comment: What did you change? And why did you change it?

Comment: instead of declaring temporary object containing selected and availables, i declared temporary selected and temporary availables and set them inside hooks.

Comment: @BinayaRijal And why would you expect that to change anything in the behaviour somehow?